# How to disable tooltip in the browser with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to disable browser tooltip from displaying when hovering over elements that have attribute 'title' populated? Note that I don't want to remove title content.
Here is the code are requested:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('a.clickableSticky').cluetip({
         splitTitle: '|',
         showTitle: false,
         titleAttribute: 'description',
         activation: 'click',
         sticky: true,
         arrows: true,
         closePosition: 'title'
     });
 });
```

and in asp.net

```
  <ItemTemplate>
     <a class="clickableSticky" href="#"
     title=' <%#((Limit)Container.DataItem).Tip %>'>
     <img src="..\App_Themes\default\images\icons\information.png"/>
     </a>

 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You can update your original question to state that - you don't need to post it as a comment :)

Comment: What browser is displaying the browser tooltip before Cluetip kicks in? I've tested in Safari, Chrome, IE8 (and 7 compat.), Firefox, and Opera and none had any problems that I could notice.

Comment: do you have a link to any of your code?

Comment: What attribute are you using to populate the cluetip content? if you use the title attribute then it will disable the showing of the title when hovering over....

Comment: I played around with settings and this seems to occur only when cluetip's activation setting is set to click. If it is activated on hover then it works, but if it is activated on click then it shows the tooltip.

Answer (score 53):

You could remove the `title` attribute on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
});
```

If you need to use the title later, you can store it in the element's jQuery `data()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $.data(this, 'title', $this.attr('title'));
        $this.removeAttr('title');
    });
});
```

Another option is to change the name of the `title` attribute to `aTitle`, or something else that the browser would ignore, and then update any JavaScript to read the new attribute name instead of `title`.

**Update:**

An interesting idea you could use is to "lazily" remove the title when hovering over an element. When the user hovers off the element, you can then put the title value back.

This isn't as straightforward as it should be because IE doesn't correctly remove the tooltip on the hover event if you set the title attribute to `null` or remove the title attribute. However, if you set the tooltip to an empty string (`""`) on hover, it will remove the tooltip from all browsers including Internet Explorer.

You can use the method I mentioned above to store the title attribute in jQuery's `data(...)` method and then put it back on `mouseout`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').mouseover(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title'));
        // Using null here wouldn't work in IE, but empty string will work just fine.
        $this.attr('title', '');
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool snippet, didn't really think through how I would've done it but I like the easiness of this approach

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, storing in description field, but I thought I could have it in title and ignore it

Comment: If you're wanting to keep the titles there, this won't work. Likely, this will break screen-readers for the visually-impaired.

Comment: As if screen-readers are going to interpret Javascript anyways...?  C'mon people!

Comment: Screen readers are quite capable of dealing with JavaScript. However, it is safe to assume they will never trigger the `hover` event so mangling the title on hover would be legitimate.

Comment: Just implemented the hover idea and it worked marvelously: )) Thanks!

Comment: Youtube currently uses the hover/remove title, hoverout/replacetitle method.
Click any youtube video, click the share tab, inspect the buttons.
So if your like me and tend to follow what has proven to be successful, you might take youtube's lead.

Comment: Using this to remove the title tooltip for colorbox (lightbox, fancybox) I found that you will have to restore the title attribute not only on `mouseout`, but also on `click`. Not restoring it on click will not restore it before colorbox starts opening. If not restored, the title won't be loaded within the colorbox title area.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the *modern* jQuery way to do it (IMO)...

```
$('[title]').attr('title', function(i, title) {
    $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');
});
```

...and of course, reading the `title` attribute back is done with...

```
$('#whatever').data('title');
```

Answer (score 8):

Following Dan Herbert's suggestion above, here is the code:

```
$(element).hover(
    function () {
        $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).removeAttr('title');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery to remove the contents of the title attribte, or move it into some other parameter for later use.

This does mean you lose some accessibility though.

**RE: ClueTip**
A search of Google seems to suggest this is a common problem - is this only happening in IE? ClueTip seems to work as expected in FireFox.

Comment: I don't want to remove title attribute. I am using 'Cluetip' plugin, and I need the title attribute. Problem is that that ugly yellow tooltipe appears for a second, before cluetip shows up.

Comment: @epitka - You could have mentioned that in question.

Comment: I am sorry, after I posted it I noticed it and revised it

Answer (score 3):

```
function hideTips(event) {  
    var saveAlt = $(this).attr('alt');
    var saveTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).attr('title','');
        $(this).attr('alt','');
    } else {
        if (event.type == 'mouseleave'){
            $(this).attr('alt',saveAlt);
            $(this).attr('title',saveTitle);
        }
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").live("hover", hideTips);
});
```

Hi all. I am using this solution and it works fine in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Hack up `ClueTip` to use a renamed title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As I need this functionality to be available during another action (as copy screen or pick color,) my solution contains two functions   to be called when that action starts and when it ends:

```
$.removeTitles = function() {
    $('[title]').bind('mousemove.hideTooltips', function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('title') && $this.attr('title') != '') { 
        $this.data('title', $this.attr('title')).attr('title', '');
    }
  }).bind('mouseout.hideTooltips', function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('title', $this.data('title'));
  });
}

$.restoreTitles = function() {
    $('[title]').unbind('mousemove.hideTooltips').unbind('mouseout.hideTooltips');
    $('*[data-title!=undefined]').attr('title', $this.data('title'));
}
```

MouseEnter cannot be used because other element(s) could lay over the titled element (as an image in a titled div) and than mouseOut will occur as soon as hover over the inner element (the image!)

However when using mouseMove you should pay attention because the event fires multiple times. To avoid wiping the saved data, check first that the title is not empty!

The last line in RemoveTitles, attempts to restore the title from the element from which the mouse did not exit when calling the end on mouseClick or on a shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery to hide the title tooltips. Here is a pure JavaScript solution that removes all the tooltips, doesn't need jQuery, keeps the possibility to click on the link, and preserves the accessibility by adding an aria-label instead of the title attribute:

```
function hide_title_attributes(el){
  var t = el.querySelectorAll('[title]');
  if(t && t.length > 0){
    for(var n=0;n<t.length;++n){
      var title=t[n].title;
      t[n].removeAttribute('title');
      t[n].setAttribute('aria-label',title);
    }
  }
}
hide_title_attributes(document.body);
document.body.onmouseover = function(e){
  if(e.target.innerHTML.indexOf('title=')>-1){
    hide_title_attributes(e.target);   
  }
  else if(e.target.title){
    var t=e.target.title;
    e.target.removeAttribute('title');
    e.target.setAttribute('aria-label',t);     
  }
}
```

This script will keep the information provided by the titles thanks to the aria-label. The aria-label will also preserve the accessibility of the page for all those users who have sight problems and use a device that reads the aria-label.