# Disable tooltip on some elements even when title is defined

Tags: tooltip, lightbox

Is there a way *not* to show a tooltip when the title of an element is defined ?

Im using huddletogether's LightBox2 which takes whatever is in the anchor's title and converts into HTML.

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#support

> Can I insert links in the caption?

Im calling a javascript function in that link and that tooltip shows this when the mouse hovers the image.

```
<a href="javascript:foo();">Click</a>
```

Other option is to change **return [anchor.href, anchor.title];** to something like **return [anchor.href, anchor.aTitle];** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027762/jquery-how-to-disable-tooltip).