# Reading jQuery Data Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable the title value, so the hover doesn't show up, and still read its value. According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027762/jquery-how-to-disable-tooltip), the following should work:

```
    $("[title]").each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $.data(this, "title", $this.attr("title"));
        $this.removeAttr("title");
    });
```

Which does remove the title property, the only problem is, I can't for the life of me figure out how to read that data value. I know it's a simple question, but I'd really appreciate the help, the jQuery documentation didn't help me on this.

What I currently have is: 
            `var description = $(this).find("img").data(this, "title");` which doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code example you gave could be tidied up a bit with the latest jQuery versions...

You probably want something like this...

```
$('[title]').attr('title', function(i, title) {
    $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');
});
```

This will assign the `title` attribute to the data store of each element with a `title` attribute, and then remove the `title` attribute of the element.

Then you can read an element's old `title` attribute with...

```
$('.something').data('title');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHjSp/).

Comment: Thank you, that worked great :) I'll accept it in just a minute.