# Chromium SVG hover <title> tooltip weirdness

Tags: google-chrome, svg, hover, tooltip, chromium

In many browsers, hover mousepointer over an SVG object with a nested `<title>` and the title text appears as a tooltip.  I'm discovering something strange happens in Chrome if adjacent objects have the same title: the tooltip is not redisplayed when you mouseover from one object to the other.

This can be replicated with the following code/fiddle.  In IE, you get a fresh tooltip for each object.

How can I work around this issue?  I need to use Chromium and I need the same tooltip to reappear over adjacent objects.  I don't really want to get into (more) scripting unless it can be done in a super lightweight, reliable and flawless with SVG.

Perhaps I can embed something invisible into the title text to make Chromium think each object's title is different?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" stroke="black">
    <title>square</title>
</rect>
<rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" stroke="black">
    <title>square</title>
</rect>
<rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" stroke="black">
    <title>square</title>
</rect>
<rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" stroke="black">
    <title>SQUARE</title>
</rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvZfR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one approach that works: put some `&zwnj;` or `&zwj;` into the title text.  These are zero-width invisible characters.  Different combinations of these make the title look different to Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's probably a bit heavy for your needs, also you'd have to implement a way of disabling the default tooltip display.

Given that css doesn't seem to do that job, a post in the thread here: [How to disable tooltip in the browser with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027762/how-to-disable-tooltip-in-the-browser-with-jquery) makes the suggestion that title attributes could be renamed aTitle, or something similar. Since these are actually contained within title tags, as opposed to title attributes of the rect elements, I guess you could (1) create new element, (2) copy contents of title (3) append new element before old one, (4) remove old element.

Though, I don't know if you can document.createElement('aTitle') - I can't remember if that fails or not.

Anyhoo - jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CvZfR/25/