# Is it possible to hide the title from a link with CSS?

Tags: html, css, hide, anchor, title

I have an anchor element with a title attribute. I want to hide the popup that appears when hovering over it in the browser window.
In my case, it is not possible to do something like this,

```
$("a").attr("title", "");
```

Because of jQuery Mobile the title will reappear after certain events occur (basically everytime the anchor element gets redrawn).
So I hope to hide the title via CSS.

Something like:

```
a[title] {
    display : none;
}
```

doesn't work, since it hides the entire anchor element. I want to hide the title only. Is this even possible? The popup shouldn't display.

Comment: no, you can't hide the tooltips. that's not part of the css spec.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable tooltip in the browser with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027762/how-to-disable-tooltip-in-the-browser-with-jquery)

Comment: That's too bad. I will have to find something else then.

Comment: @Gatekeeper It's a tooltip which is created by jQuery Mobile, so I'm pretty much stuck with it. I just want it to hide :)

Comment: Another idea (much less elegant than what you're looking for, but gets the job done): You could change the behavior of jQuery Mobile. I wouldn't directly change the source (not generally good practice), but you could write an extension that hooks in and removes the title after it renders the elements.

Comment: You say it's not possible to do `$("a").attr("title", "");` in your case. Is this because you have some constraints, or because you tried and it didn't work? If it just didn't work, you may instead need to do `$('a').prop('title', '');` since `attr` != `prop` in jQuery >= 1.6..

Comment: @Aaron Yep, that's what I did. My plugin creates a slider that steps in hexadecimal steps. I registered handlers for 'slidestop' and 'mouseover', hiding the title attribute, but while dragging the slider it still shows.

Comment: @Noyo Contraints. I did the $("a").attr("title", "") in a lot of events, but there are still some in which I cannot hook into. See my answer to Aaron.

Comment: In which events? `slidestart` and `slidestop`?

Comment: Do you by any chance know how the plugin creates this tooltip? If so you may be able to target that and hide it instead of the `a`.

Comment: @BoltClock jQuery Mobile updates it everytime in it's refresh method, so it's not part of the plugin.

Comment: @Noyo Both `slidestop` and `slidestart`

Answer (score 32):

Using the following CSS property will ensure that the title attribute text does not appear upon hover:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Keep in mind that JS is a better solution since this CSS property will ensure that the element is never the target of any mouse events.

Comment: This will also disable any functions following clicking on the link. Which renders the whole link pointless.

Comment: Yes @Hafenkranich, that's why in my answer I wrote "Keep in mind that JS is a better solution since this CSS property will ensure that the element is never the target of any mouse events."

Comment: In Safari the title keeps showing up, even with `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 15):

You can wrap your inner text in a span and give that an empty title attribute.

```html
<a href="" title="Something">
  <span title="">Your text</span>
</a>
```

Comment: SEO is gonna love this

Comment: this would be a nice solution, unfortunately doesn't work for all browsers (eg. Safari shows the tooltip by using the parent `title` if the `title` of the target element is empty)

Comment: If you're going mangle an accessibility feature like that you're better off simply not using it in the first place.

Comment: This turned out to be the only viable solution in a managed environment like MediaWiki.

Comment: Danng, very clever.

Answer (score 12):

As per @boltClock's suggestion, I'll say I don't feel that a CSS solution is appropriate here, as the browser decides what to do with the title attribute of a link, or anything for that matter. CSS, to my knowledge, is unable to handle this issue.

As mentioned, using jQuery to replace the title with an empty string wont work because jQuery mobile rewrites them at some points. This, however, will work independently of JQM, and doesn't involve entirely removing the title attribute which is SEO important.

This works:

```
$('a["title"]').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

*I changed my initial code of `$('body').on('mouseenter')` to this after testing. This is confirmed to work.*

Comment: Moving my comment from the other answer to here: this doesn't look like CSS to me.

Comment: well, @BoltClock, that's because it isn't. the OP only said that something like the jquery script HE/SHE included wouldn't work. Because he's using jquery mobile, I'm rightfully assuming that jquery is being used for his project, and that a jquery answer (that works) would be fair game.

Comment: if jquery can't handle an event, css sure as heckfire cannot either.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying you need to mention that it isn't (possible with) CSS because the question specifically asked to do it via CSS, not jQuery.

Comment: This doesn't work (anymore), at least not with the latest jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS it's not possible, because you can only add contents to DOM (tipically with `:before :after` and `content: '...';`, not remove or change attributes.

The only way is to create a live custom event (es. `"change-something"`):

`$("a").on("change-something", function(event) { this.removeAttr("title"); });`

and trigger to every changes:

`... $("a").trigger("change-something");`

More information and demo here:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 2):

try to change your code using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").removeAttr("title");
});
```

this will remove title attribute so the hint label won't be appear when hover on the link

Comment: SEO and hidden/removed content

Answer (score 0):

Full working pure javascript solution

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[title]');
    for (let i = anchors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
        anchors[i].setAttribute('data-title', anchors[i].title);
        anchors[i].removeAttribute('title');
        
    });
    anchors[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
        anchors[i].title = anchors[i].getAttribute('data-title');
        anchors[i].removeAttribute('data-title');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#test").tooltip({title: false});
```

There `title` attribute default value is `true`, make it `false`.
This will work only in case of **Bootstrap Tooltip**

Answer (score 0):

```js
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeFilter: ['title'],
};
const removeTitleAttribute = (element, observer) => {
  if (element.hasAttribute('title')) {
    element.removeAttribute('title');
  }
};
const removeTitleByObserveDOM = () => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node: HTMLElement) => {
          if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            const components = node.querySelectorAll('[title]');
            components.forEach(component => removeTitleAttribute(component, observer));
          }
        });
      } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'title') {
        removeTitleAttribute(mutation.target, observer);
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(document.querySelector('#root'), config);
  return observer;
};
export default removeTitleByObserveDOM;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution that removes all the tooltips, doesn't need jQuery, keeps the possibility to click on the link, and preserves the accessibility by adding an aria-label instead of the title attribute:

```
function hide_title_attributes(el){
  var t = el.querySelectorAll('[title]');
  if(t && t.length > `enter code here`0){
    for(var n=0;n<t.length;++n){
      var title=t[n].title;
        t[n].removeAttribute('title');
        t[n].setAttribute('aria-label',title);
      }
    }
}
hide_title_attributes(document.body);
document.body.onmouseover = function(e){
  if(e.target.innerHTML.indexOf('title=')>-1){
    hide_title_attributes(e.target);   
  }
  else if(e.target.title){
    var t=e.target.title;
      e.target.removeAttribute('title');
      e.target.setAttribute('aria-label',t);     
    }
}
```