# HTML/CSS how can I hide the url text which appears when i hover over a menu bar

Tags: html, css

When i hover over the button on my sites menu bar a little box appears, for exmaple when i hover over Home a little box comes up saying "Home".

Is there any pure HTML/CSS way to hide this? I notice that normal sites such as stackoverflow have this turned off.

Thanks

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Home" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>
```

Comment: Please share the code for the button/menu where it appears.

Comment: It sounds like your links have a title attribute on them (eg `title="Home"`).  Just remove this.  But to help us better, please provide your html in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364063/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-title-from-a-link-with-css

Comment: <a href="javascript:;" title="Home" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>

Comment: thanks guys for being helpful :) I am asking for a HTML/CSS fix which i possible so I made a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `title` attribute, change:

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Home" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:;" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>
```

Comment: great thanks, will mark this as the answer in a few minutes when it lets me

Comment: in terms of SEO aren't these title attributes very important? is it possible to just prevent it showing up, but retain it? if not then this is perfect

Comment: Not really, the title attributes are more for accessibility than seo and then I would only use them in the case where the text in the link doesn't really explain what it is doing so you need the title to explain it instead.

Comment: is the Title of the page not what comes up as the main text in a google search though? what happens if there is no title attribtue, does it just take the text of the link

Comment: this is the `title` **attribute**: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html.   The thing you are talking about is the `title` **tag** in the head of the document - http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the title attribute as it creates a popup displaying the value given to title. You will have to remove the title attribute from where you don't want it.

```
<a href="javascript:;" aria-haspopup="true"><span>Home</span></a>
```

You can learn more about the title attribute from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp