# I get two link titles

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the link titles. I tried to style the link title with css. My css is :

```
a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  padding: 2px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px solid #bce8f1;
  background-color:#d9edf7;
  color:#31708f;
  font-weight:700;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #bce8f1;
  z-index:99999999;
}
```

But when I hover over the link, I get this styled title but I get also the old one like on the photo.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt you can do anything about this without using JavaScript to change the title attribute to something else and basing your CSS on that new attribute.

Comment: Because your pseudo-element and title are different elements.

Comment: Any suggestions how to hide the old title? With javascript or with css?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364063/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-title-from-a-link-with-css

Comment: I tried something like `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
});` . But now i do not see title at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the title attribute which has a default action/style, I'd create my own.

```
<a href="/someplace.html" data-title="The Title of Someplace">Someplace</a>
```

Then you would change the CSS to reflect the new attribute.

```
a[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `data-title` instead of `title`:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="mailto:info@vermistedieren.be" data-title="Als u nog vragen heeft, stel ze gerust. Wij staan tot uw dienst!">
```

**CSS:**

```
a[data-title]:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  ...
}
```