# Hide Link Text Within Media Query - WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Unfortunately it looks like [you can't hide link text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364063/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-title-from-a-link-with-css). On my WordPress site, at 375 px and below, the titles of the links in the `secondary-navbar` start to overlap.

[image]

[Please see for yourself](http://gatewaywebdesign.com/)

What I'm trying to do is to say "as soon as the titles start to overlap (at 375px and below), make the titles disappear." I'd also like to make the glyphicons larger and centered.

Here's a link to my [header.php file](http://pastebin.com/zptF9EpW). I didn't write the code for this site and am not very familiar with the `wp_nav_menu` function, but I would guess that it's probably line 62 that's causing the menu titles to appear in the div with the `nav navbar-nav secondary-links` class.

So then, if that is the problem, how do we get that specific part of the function to disappear at 375px and below?

I tried commenting out line 62 and got a pretty bad result:

[image]

Please point me in the right direction if you have any suggestions / ideas. Maybe there's a way to disable the titles with JQuery? Thank you.

Comment: For another time, if you need to ask this type of question again, please don't use the word "title" to describe link-text - a "title" is the attribute "title" which is set on all of those elements, and which you should get rid of (maybe apart from when you only have the icons), because the title as it is set today has the exact same content as the link-text itself. Bad design. Also, if that theme had been designed properly, the text inside the `<a>`-tags would have been wrapped in a `<span>` by itself, and you could've just hidden that span in the @media-query.

Comment: Okay yeah you're right - link text instead of title. Those are good points about the design - I don't disagree with you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution put it in the end of the stylesheet file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
   .secondary-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a{font-size:0px;}
   .secondary-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{font-size:0px;}
   .secondary-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a span{font-size:20px!important;}
}
```

Comment: Oh so you just set font-size to 0 - genius. Thank you.